# Create document from xp:dialog - Object has been removed or recycled

Tags: xpages

For a xp:panel in a xp:dialog I have defined a dominoDocument datasource as followed:

```
<xp:this.data>
    <xp:dominoDocument formName="fa_Attachment" var="attachmentDoc">
    </xp:dominoDocument>
</xp:this.data>
```

Somewhere within the panel I have added an Edit Box:

When I open the dialog I get the following error message:

> Unexpected runtime error The runtime has encountered an unexpected
>   error. Error source Page Name:/matter.xsp
>
> Exception javax.faces.el.EvaluationException:
>   com.ibm.xsp.FacesExceptionEx: Notes exception thrown while calling
>   DominoDocument.getValue() on field test com.ibm.xsp.FacesExceptionEx:
>   Notes exception thrown while calling DominoDocument.getValue() on
>   field test Notes exception thrown while calling
>   DominoDocument.getValue() on field test Object has been removed or
>   recycled

What can be the cause?

Comment: the object must be the database. the reference to it is computed and resides in a different NSF